# How to change the position of menu item?

Tags: menu-order

How do I change the position of the Products menu? I created it by hard coding, using the code below.

[image]

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images' );
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_my_terms', 10, 2 );

function add_my_terms( $items ) {
    global $post;        
    $items .= '<li class="dropdown  "><a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products</a><ul class="dropdown-menu  coldrpprd ">';
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    $nmr=0;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $term->term_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );        
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        $nmr++ ;         
        if ( $nmr <= 3 ) {
            $items .= '<li class="menuli">'.'<img class="category-image " src="'.$image.'">'.'<a  href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            $items .= '<ul>';
            foreach ( $subcats as $sc ) {
                $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
                $items .= '<li class="wooc_sclist"><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
            }
            $items .=  '</ul>';
        }
    }
    $items .= '</ul></li>';        
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: By change position, do you mean change the order of the list items? Like instead of Contatti - Privacy - Products, it would be Contatti - Products - Privacy

Comment: Also, do you have any more "dynamic" submenus or just the Products one? There's a few different ways to do this depending on the situation.

Comment: Hello Bryan , There is only one dynamic submenu ,jus Products , I just want it to be at second position Servizi >Product > Download >Contatti >Privacy

Comment: What are you doing to output the other menus, Servizi -  Download -  Contatti - Privacy ? Are Servizi -  Download -  Contatti - Privacy all part of the same menu?

Comment: Yes all they are part of the same menu , main menu , just the Product is  included there by using this code , and it is showing into dynamic mode ,all the categories and subcategories of woocomerce , I hope you get the idea How is it working ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubermenu is great, but probably unnecessary if this is all you're trying to do. There are a ton of different ways to do this. Here's a couple:

---

**1) Custom Walker**

```
<?php
// custom walker targeting products menu
class productMenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {

    if( 'Products' == $item->title ){
        // PRODUCT SUBMENU STUFF
        $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">




        </ul>';
    }
    $output .= "</li>\n";  
    }
}


// new menu with walker
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'walker' => new productMenu
    )
);
```

**2) Just add the ones you want after products to the filter as well**

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_my_terms', 10, 2 );

function add_my_terms( $items ) {
    global $post;        
    $items .= '<li class="dropdown  "><a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products</a><ul class="dropdown-menu  coldrpprd ">';
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    $nmr=0;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $term->term_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );        
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        $nmr++ ;         
        if ( $nmr <= 3 ) {
            $items .= '<li class="menuli">'.'<img class="category-image " src="'.$image.'">'.'<a  href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            $items .= '<ul>';
            foreach ( $subcats as $sc ) {
                $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
                $items .= '<li class="wooc_sclist"><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
            }
            $items .=  '</ul>';
        }
    }
    $items .= '</ul></li><li><a href="#">Products</a></li>';        
    return $items;
    return 
}
```

**3) Just use your function without wp_nav_menu() and hardcode it all. Is it really necessary to have to have those menus editable in the backend? If not just do this:**

```
<ul>
<li>Servizi</li>
<?php echo add_my_terms(); ?>
<li>Download</li>
<li>Contatti</li>
<li>Pricacy</li>
</ul>
```

**4) If you really want to make this work without walker you could probably use `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` and search for product menu item by id and add submenu, but this is unnecessarily complicated for your task in my opinion.**

**5) Create two separate menus one before and one after your custom php.**

```
  <?php wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary_before',
        )
    ); ?>
   <ul>
   <?php echo add_my_terms(); ?>
   </ul>
   <?php wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary_after'
        )
    ); ?>
```

**6) Use shortcodes.**

```
// Turn function into shortcode
function add_my_terms( $items ) {
    global $post;        
    $items .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu  coldrpprd ">';
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    $nmr=0;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $term->term_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );        
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        $nmr++ ;         
        if ( $nmr <= 3 ) {
            $items .= '<li class="menuli">'.'<img class="category-image " src="'.$image.'">'.'<a  href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            $items .= '<ul>';
            foreach ( $subcats as $sc ) {
                $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
                $items .= '<li class="wooc_sclist"><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
            }
            $items .=  '</ul>';
        }
    }
    $items .= '</ul>';        
    return $items;
}
add_shortcode('product_submenu', 'add_my_terms');



// Allow shortcodes to render in menu description fields
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'do_shortcode', 11);
if( !function_exists('shortcode_my_menu_descriptions') ) {
    function shortcode_my_menu_descriptions( $item_output, $item ) {
        if ( !empty($item->description)) {
             $output = do_shortcode($item->description);
             if ( $output != $item->description )
                  $item_output = $output;  
            }
        return $item_output;    
    }
    add_filter("walker_nav_menu_start_el", "shortcode_my_menu_descriptions" , 10 , 2);
}
```

Using this method you can create your menu as normal in the order you want and then just add `[product_submenu]` in the description field in the product menu item.

**7) Using plugins**

Beside ubermenu there is also https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-in-menus/ which can help you achieve your results and are both free.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, I appreciate your answer.It's look good This is what i need .Regards

Answer (score 0):

Interesting way of adding items to the menu there. Are you using Appearance > Menus for the rest of your menu? If not, you should be IMO.

I'd recommend using [uber menu](http://wpmegamenu.com) to do this, the plugin is worth it's weight in gold (not affiliated, just have used it and highly recommend it) - in uber menu you can add dynamic content such as terms to your menu - see this tutorial: http://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/advanced-menu-items/dynamic-terms

Comment: Yes i'm using the Apparence > Menu ..., but i need only this menu item to be dynamic.I checked this plugin before , but i really dont want to change the menu style , i just want to make this item dynamic , and I did it by hard coding , Now I just need to change the position of this Item , to be lets say at second position ,Is there any simple way . Thank you for your replay .

Comment: No worries, you don't have to change your menu style - I've used uber menu to many kinds of design configurations. I just use it as a base for every site now so I have the option of adding dynamic items easily. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Nathan ,I appreciate your comment , Im going to check for this plugin , Regards